# Restarting inifinite Flux on error with pubSubReactiveFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, google-cloud-pubsub, reactor

I'm developing an application which uses reactor libraries to connect with Google pubsub. So I have a Flux of messages. I want it to always consume from the queue, no matter what happens: this means handling all errors in order not to terminate the flux. I was thinking about the (very unlikely) event the connection to pubsub may be lost or whatever may cause the just created Flux to signal an error. I came up with this solution:

```java
    private final PubSubReactiveFactory pubSubReactiveFactory;
    private final String requestSubscription;
    private final Long requestPollTime;
    private final Flux<AcknowledgeablePubsubMessage> requestFlux;

    @Autowired
    public FluxContainer(/* Field args...*/) {
        // init stuff...
        this.requestFlux = initRequestFlux();
    }

    private Flux<AcknowledgeablePubsubMessage> initRequestFlux() {
        return pubSubReactiveFactory.poll(requestSubscription, requestPollTime);
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("FATAL ERROR: could not retrieve message from queue. Resetting flux", e))
                .onErrorResume(e -> initRequestFlux());
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void configureFluxAndSubscribe() {
        log.info("Setting up requestFlux...");
        this.requestFlux
                .doOnNext(AcknowledgeablePubsubMessage::ack)
                // ...many more concatenated calls handling flux
    }
```

Does it makes sense? I'm concerned about memory allocation (I'm relying on the gc to clean stuff). Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Is not clear what your question is. You would like to know how to handle errors in Flux or you have an specific doubt related to the errors Pub/Sub may thrown?

Comment: A general approach on restarting Flux (that is actually what I implemented, but was not able to test) would be a suitable answer. Thinking there may be specific issues according to the underlying implementation of the pubsub Flux, I put the question in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is basically a `Flux` that restarts itself when it is terminated for any situation except for the subscription being disposed.  In my case I have a source that would generate infinite events from Docker daemon which can disconnect "successfully"

Let `sourceFlux` be the flux providing your data and would be something you'd want to restart on error or complete, but stop on subscription disposal.

1. create a recovery function

   ```java
   Function<Throwable, Publisher<Integer>> recoverFromThrow =
           throwable -> sourceFlux
   ```
2. create a new flux that would recover from throw

   ```java
   var recoveringFromThrowFlux =
     sourceFlux.onErrorResume(recoverFromThrow);
   ```
3. create a Flux generator that generates the flux that would recover from a throw.  (Note the generic coercion is needed)

   ```java
   var foreverFlux =
     Flux.<Flux<Integer>>generate((sink) -> sink.next(recoveringFromThrowFlux))
       .flatMap(flux -> flux);
   ```

`foreverFlux` is the flux that does self recovery.